# R Shiny grep javascript

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, grepl

I want to be able to use `grepl` in a `conditionalPanel` function.

Here is a MWE. In this one, I test that my input is explicitely one of the possibilities.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  column(5, wellPanel(
    uiOutput("test")
  )
  ),

  column(7,
         conditionalPanel("input.essai_res == 'first choice.xlsx'",
                           p("test")
         )

  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$test <- renderUI({
    selectInput("essai_res", h3("Test"), c("first choice.xlsx", "second choice.xlsx"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Instead of that, I'd like to be able to test that the string "first" is part of the choice for example.

I tried

```
conditionalPanel("grepl('first', input.essai_res)", p("test"))

conditionalPanel("'first'.test(input.essai_res)", p("test"))
```

the second one I did it to try a JavaScript command.

In those 2 cases, whatever the choice in the list, "test" always appears.

What can I do in order to have "test" appears only when "first" is part of the choices?

I add this comment to answer a question below about the context. The choices come from those command lines:

```
files_list <- list.files(path = "Data/", pattern = "\\.xlsx$|\\.xlsm$", full.names = TRUE)
files_names <- substring(files_list, 6)
files_list <- as.list(files_list)
names(files_list) <- files_names

if (length(files_list) == 0){files_list <- "No files in the folder \"Data\""}

output$path_res <- renderUI({
    selectInput("essai_a", h3("Title"), files_list)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regex: `"(/first/).test(input.essai_res)`".

Comment: While this does answer the question, can you provide additional context and a working example?

Comment: Thanks @stephane I saw that it requiered a regex expression, but I didn't know how to make it. So one has to delimite the expression with `(/.../)`, right?

Comment: @EtherDragon The choices come from a `list.files` with the pattern `xlsx|xlsm` from a directory, and then among those name's files, in case some of those names have a certain pattern, I need to do display a panel to get more options. The working example is acutally pretty long

Comment: @EtherDragon I edited the main post to answer (maybe?) your question

Answer (score 3):

You can use `includes` but note that it will not work in IE:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  column(
    width = 5, wellPanel(
      selectInput("essai_res", h3("Test"), c("first choice.xlsx", "second choice.xlsx"))
    )
  ),

  column(
    width = 7,
    conditionalPanel(
      "input.essai_res.includes('first')",
      p("test")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you @Victorp ! Since it does not work with IE, I validated the previous answer. But I keep your too!